# Android Studio HAXM not working

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I want to use android studio on a hp with E2 AMD vision processor. 
The problem is that when I download the HAXM installer from the SDK manager and try to install it I get an error saying that my computer does not support this program. I went to the BIOS settings, enabled the VT option then I went to see the Hyper-V option in "Turn Window Features on and off" and it's already unchecked but I'm still getting the same problem. 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use HAXM because it's only for Intel processors:

> The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a
>   hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel
>   Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT) to speed up Android app
>   emulation on a host machine. In combination with Android x86 emulator
>   images provided by Intel and the official Android SDK Manager, HAXM
>   allows for faster Android emulation on Intel VT enabled systems.

You should try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), it supports VT-X and also AMD-v.